# Can I use tensor flow GPU without a graphics card? Outsource training to AWS/Cloud?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, gpu

**Background**

I have a school project that has this specific item I want to construct an object detector for. I was planning on making a custom dataset, labeling the image, and then using tensorflow to train my classifier.

I was reading an article and it said if I didn't have a gpu with 2GB or more it would be better to train the dataset on AWS or google cloud.

**Question**

My question is could I still write the code and configuration files on my laptop, which has no GPU, and then outsource the training to AWS or google cloud?

I'm very new to this so I'm not sure if I'm overlooking some sort of dependencies that will prevent me from moving forward.

If I can't move forward with my given hardware what are my other options I guess?

Answer (score 0):

You can use free Google COLAB, they have their inbuilt GPU.

https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/welcome.ipynb

Google Colab is a free cloud service and now it supports free GPU!

Comment: Hey Bira, I'm following this tutorial: "How To Train an Object Detection Classifier Using TensorFlow 1.5 (GPU) on Windows 10" in order to use the 'faster r_cnn" training model I have to have tensorflow gpu installed and cuda. If I went with google collab how exactly would I reference this training method?

Answer (score 0):

Use Kaggle kernel to run and save the file in system thats a easy and smart way out.